# Redisplaying div in flex layout after display:none

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, flexbox

I have two aside divs (essentially two side bars) which must be hidden to enable a "fullscreen" of my central div `main`, I am using flexbox to assign proportions of the screen, however, upon redisplaying the elements as `display : block`, it completely ruins the original layout.
The code for hiding and displaying is below. I am using d3 for DOM manipulation.

```
function handlefullscreen(){
    if(d3.select("#fullscreen").attr("data-selected") == 1){
        d3.select("#fullscreen").attr("data-selected", 0);
        d3.selectAll(".aside")
            .style("display", "block")
            .transition()
            .ease(d3.easeCubic)
            .duration("250")
            .style("opacity", 1).on("end",
                redraw);
    } else{
        previousWidth = document.getElementById('left').offsetWidth;
        d3.select("#fullscreen").attr("data-selected", 1);
        d3.selectAll(".aside")
            .transition()
            .ease(d3.easeCubic)
            .duration("250")
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .on("end", function(){
                d3.select(this).style("display", "none"); 
                redraw();
            });
    }
}
```

Below is the CSS I am using for the flex elements:

```
     .wrapper {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0 -10px;
         display: flex;  
         flex-flow: row wrap;
         font-weight: bold;
         text-align: center;
     }

     .wrapper > * {
         padding: 0px;
     }

     .main {
         background: #ffffff;
     }

     .aside-1 {
         box-shadow:5px 1px 6px #4E565E;
         background: #d8d8d8;
         z-index: 1;
     }

     .aside-2 {
         margin: 0 0px;
         box-shadow:-5px 1px 6px #4E565E;
         background: #d8d8d8;
     }

     @media all and (min-width: 600px) {
         .aside { flex: 1 20%; }
     }

     @media all and (min-width: 800px) {
         .main    { flex: 3 60%; }
         .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
         .main    { order: 2; }
         .aside-2 { order: 3; }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the display block to display flex.

```
d3.selectAll(".aside")
        .style("display", "flex")
        .... // rest of the code
```

Remember that flex is another mode for the display property.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, by default the element is already `display: block`. I'm pretty sure anything that isn't `display: none` automatically becomes a flex item if it's inside a flex wrapper.

Comment: Hi, yes for that element the default `display: block`, but you can change it. Did you try to change the code as I told you? Can you make a jsfiddle with all the code you we can see what you are trying to do?